# How can i know through which mysql router request has been sent to InnoDB cluster in a multirouter environment

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqlrouter

I had configured my Java application to connect through multiple routers to the InnoDB cluster so that if one of my router stops working other router can take up the routing task (I have 6 router configured )

Now  Can some one help me in finding through which router request has been sent in a multirouter setuP ?

Comment: What type/brand of "router"?  DNS, VIP, HAProxy, MySQL router, etc, etc?

Comment: Type of routers deployed -  MySQL router

Comment: Just to confirm - do you mean [MySQL Router](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/) which is a component of InnoDB Cluster?

Comment: Yes adjectly MySQL Router which is a component of InnoDB Cluster